# Sencha Touch 2 NestedList goToNode() is not working

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am invoking `goToNode()` like so:

`nestedList.goToNode(Ext.create('myStore').getRoot());`

The list shows the `title` in the toolbar correctly with no back button (so it seems like we're at the root), but the actual items in the list (the `children`) are not correct. They are leaves, and one is selected -- the last one I tapped.

I am navigating through a `NestedList` and end up at a `detailCard`. I transition to another view, and once I'm finished at that view, I want to go back to the `NestedList` at the very "top" of the list. I thought I could use `goToNode()` but it isn't working. How can I do this? It seems to me that `goToNode` is not working correctly.